# How to use enum from another class and file withouot repetitive scoping? c++

Tags: c++

I feel like this is an easy question but I don't seem to find the answer myself. I was wondering if there is a way of using the enum in another file, without having to use scoping?
e.g. `Head.h`

```
namespace h{
class Eye{
 enum class State{
  closed = 0, blinking, open, staring, rolling // etc.
 };
 void print(const State &eye);
};
class Body{
  Eye::State eye;
  Eye::State eyesOpen();

};
}
```

`Head.cpp`

```
namespace h{
 void Eye::print(const State &eye){
  switch(eye){
     case Eye::State::closed: cout << "Closed" << endl;
     case Eye::State::blinking: cout << "Blinking" << endl;
     case Eye::State::open: cout << "Open" << endl;

 }

 bool Body::eyesOpen(){
   return eye == Eye::open;
 }
}
```

I am using Eye::State about 80+ times in my Body class, so I was wondering if there's a way for me to just state that `State` is `Eye::State` rather than having to write it 80 times?

Edit: `Eye` and `Body` are two separate classes. It's just that `Body` uses the `Eye` object

Comment: Use a normal type alias, `using State = Eye::State;`

Comment: You don't even need a type alias for any references by other members of the same class. `State::closed`, et. al., in the shown code, will simply work as is.

Comment: Be aware, though, that if you *do* alias states this way it shouldn't just be for convenience, but the aliased type should fit to the enclosing type (or namespace). In given example, it doesn't; or what would a blinking body mean (`Body::State::Blinking`)???

Comment: Side note: The `print` function is pretty unlucky, as it enforces printing to `std::cout` – what, if you intend printing to e.g. a file? Better: Implement `ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, Eye::State state)`, then you can do `Eye::State s; std::cout << s;` or the same for any other stream.

Comment: @molbdnilo so it should work if i put the alias at the top of the namespace?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik they are in two separate classes but in the same namespace

Comment: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum (note limitations).

Comment: Well the code you _showed_ was mostly using `Eye::State` inside the `Eye` class, where Sam's comment is exactly correct. The fact that your text describes a problem not really visible in your code sample is not ideal.

Comment: Possible typo, `Body::eyesOpen` seems to return `Eye::State` in the header, but returns `bool` in the cpp file.

Comment: @molbdnilo I guess if Eye was in an Other namespace, you could still do `using State Other::Eye::State;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put a type alias at the top of the namespace unless that's really the logical scope you want.

If you just want to save typing in the `Body` methods you haven't shown, simply

```
namespace h{
class Body{
  using State = Eye::State;
  State eye;
  State eyesOpen();
};
}
```

will work. It seems odd that the eyes are the only organ of this body whose state is important, though. If you really want more organ states later, you can remove the class-level alias and just write

```
bool Body::eyesOpen() {
  using State = Eye::State;
  return eye == State::open;
}
```

(which is no improvement at all, but imagine it's applied to the other 80 instances you haven't shown us).

Comment: thanks adding the using at the start of the class worked!